# How to set cmder as default cmd in windows 10 when you get connected via SSH?

Tags: windows-10, cmder

I've installed OpenSSHUtilities and I can connect to my PC via SSH.

But when I get connected I want to have cmder console instead of cmd from windows?

Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: Doesn't cmder just run the same cmd.exe in a fancier window?

Comment: run `echo %comspec%` in cmder and you'll see that the real shell is cmd.exe (by default). It's just a terminal and not a shell

Comment: I know that cmder is only an emulator, but that is my question.... is there a way to start the cmder when you get connected via ssh to windows... or at least can I get the shell commands work in cmd.exe? For example `poweroff`